# What does Y-axis mean when displaying a complex image using ShowImage()?

Tags: dm-script

I made a 1-D complex image "c" as below and used ShowImage to display it. My question is how to understand the Y-axis.
For pixel 1 (30+40i), it looks like the value in Y-axis represents log(modulus(30+40i))=3.9. But it does not seem to follow this rule in pixel 3 (0.3+0.4i).

```
ComplexImage c := ComplexImage("c", 8, 3, 1) 
c[0, 0, 1, 1] = complex(30, 40)
c[0, 1, 1, 2] = complex(3, 4)
c[0, 2, 1, 3] = complex(0.3, 0.4)
ShowImage(c)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While not actually a *scripting* question, a very interesting observation! It turns out, that the plotted or displayed values for `"Log of modulus"` really is doing:

> `log( modulus( C ) + 1 )`

And it is important to know, that the script-command `log()` is taking the *natural* logarithm. To command `log10()` would do the one to the base 10.

```
complexNumber c1 = complex(30,40)
complexNumber c2 = complex(3,4)
complexNumber c3 = complex(0.3,0.4)

result("\n Complex values:\n" )
result( "c1 = \t"+c1+"\n")
result( "c2 = \t"+c2+"\n")
result( "c3 = \t"+c3+"\n")

result("\n Modulus values:\n" )
result( "c1 = \t"+modulus(c1)+"\n")
result( "c2 = \t"+modulus(c2)+"\n")
result( "c3 = \t"+modulus(c3)+"\n")

result("\n Log of Modulus values:\n" )
result( "c1 = \t"+log10(modulus(c1))+"\n")
result( "c2 = \t"+log10(modulus(c2))+"\n")
result( "c3 = \t"+log10(modulus(c3))+"\n")

result("\n Log of Modulus + 1 values:\n" )
result( "c1 = \t"+log(modulus(c1) + 1)+"\n")
result( "c2 = \t"+log(modulus(c2) + 1)+"\n")
result( "c3 = \t"+log(modulus(c3) + 1)+"\n")
```

This gives you:

```
 Complex values:
c1 =    30 + 40 i
c2 =    3 + 4 i
c3 =    0.3 + 0.4 i

 Modulus values:
c1 =    50
c2 =    5
c3 =    0.5

 Log of Modulus values:
c1 =    1.69897
c2 =    0.69897
c3 =    -0.30103

 Log of Modulus +1 values:
c1 =    3.93183
c2 =    1.79176
c3 =    0.405465
```

Comment: The reason for this is most likely to avoid negative values in this display. the main purpose of the "log-of-modulus" display comes from using FFTs as proxies for diffraction-pattern images. The aim is (/was) to have images look "similar" to recorded diffraction patterns on film.

Answer (score 0):

```
compleximage ComplexImage( string title, number size,
number width, number height )
```

width and height are in pixels

```
number x = 512, y = 512
compleximage myImage := ComplexImage( "My Image", 16, x, y )
myImage = complex( irow, icol )
ShowImage( myImage )
```

This example creates an 512 x 512 pixel, 16 byte complex image with the title
"My Image". It then sets all pixels in the image to the expression complex(
irow, icol ). This expression is a complex image expression where the real part is the row number of every pixel and the imaginary part is the column
number of every pixel. Finally it shows the image.